# Select rows with certain values and update in R

Tags: r

I want to select rows that contain 'dm', something like like %dm% should be used, and then update them those rows by adding '*' in the beginning and the end of the string. An example would be:

```
id  text
1   abc
2   admc
```

The output:

```
id  text
 1   abc
 2   *admc*
```

Comment: If you also create a reproducible example data frame you would make life easier for those aiming to help you!

Answer (score 4):

You can identify the rows with `"dm"` using `grep`/`grepl` and change their values using `paste0`.

```
inds <- grep('dm', df$text)
df$text[inds] <- paste0('*', df$text[inds], '*')
df

#  id   text
#1  1    abc
#2  2 *admc*
```

---

Using `data.table` syntax avoids the creation of temporary variable (`inds`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[grep('dm', text), text := paste0('*', text, '*')]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, text = c("abc", "admc")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

1. First, detect the presence of "dm" with `stringr::str_detect`
2. Then, using `dplyr::if_else`, if "dm" is present, prepend/append "*" using `paste0`; else, keep the text as-is

_

```
df %>% 
  mutate(text = if_else(str_detect(text, "dm"), paste0("*", text, "*"), text))
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "id  text
                 1   abc
                 2   admc", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```